# Live cmd/bash editor with PHP, or marking a WEB C++ compiler and debugger?

Tags: php, bash, cmd, compiler-construction, g++

I am a student. I've choosed a topic for my bachelor to make a WEB C++ compiler similar to repl.it and other websites. Now I am a little stuck. I have two textareas on my website, one for code input, other for code output. If I write code without arguments (without `cin`), everything is allright, I am using php `exec` function which sends code to be compiled, and returns output. Simple, right? But then problem appeared. If I need to enter live arguments to program when it asks it with `cin >> variable;`, how to deal with these? Can php `proc_open` do that, I've googled but not found anything similar? Should I open a g++ process with PHP and check if pointer is set to write? Or there are other alternatives or plugins to sort my question? Thanks in advance. I don't need whole code to solve, I need a hint how this can be done.

I made currently it working with exec function, but I can't pass live arguments with it. I am looking for other way of solving it. I don't know how this can be done.

Comment: I've done this before, but it was not a live experience, you have to pass the input through an OS pipe to the process which will run the compiler, this can be done using the `proc_open()` function.  
I've done something similar to https://rextester.com , you have to provide all your inputs before running the process, does this work for your case or you specifically need it to be live ?